# Geo location is not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, geolocation

While trying to fetch browser location it works for all the major browsers like FF, Chrome and IE but causing issue with Safari.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
```

//logic to get location

}, function (error) { console.log(error) });

I am getting error code from safari is: error code: 2. All the error codes for geo location are : PERMISSION_DENIED: 1 POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2 TIMEOUT: 3.

Please suggest me possible changes that should work.

Thanks.

Comment: When I run that code in a situation where I expect it to fail, I get more information about the problem than you quoted. Look at the previous line. Are you sure there isn't an explanation listed in the console?

Comment: Even there is no exception occurs, the error information i got is from the consle.log or from the debugger I have put in the callback for error. @Quentin

Comment: @PrinceChopra I have the same problem at the moment, have you found what is the cause of the error?

Comment: @mnemon1ck, sorry I didn't find any solution for this.